# stored proc: if else statement inside case when

Tags: mysql, sql

```
BEGIN
    CASE x
        WHEN 0 THEN (
                    IF thisIsAVariable = 'viewAll' THEN
                       SELECT id, fname FROM Persons WHERE 1
                    ELSE
                       SELECT id, fname FROM Persons WHERE id = '1111'
                    END IF
                 );
    END CASE;
END
```

What is the correct syntax for ifelse statments inside casewhen statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use if inside the if to make code easy like below:

```
BEGIN
    IF x = 0 THEN
        IF thisIsAVariable = 'viewAll' THEN
            SELECT id, fname FROM Persons WHERE 1;
        ELSE
            SELECT id, fname FROM Persons WHERE id = '1111';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `IF-ELSE`,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procName
BEGIN
    IF x = 0 THEN
        IF thisIsAVariable = 'viewAll' THEN
            SELECT id, fname FROM Persons WHERE 1;
        ELSE
            SELECT id, fname FROM Persons WHERE id = '1111';
        END IF;
    ELSE
        -- other codes if you have
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

*I think* when using `CASE`, the select statement should return only one value.

Answer (score 0):

just try this one

```
BEGIN
    CASE x
        WHEN 0 THEN (
                    SELECT id, fname FROM Persons WHERE id = IF(thisIsAVariable = 'viewAll',1,'1111')
                 );
    END CASE;
END
```